# Connect to SQL server using default name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server 2012. I am able to connect using :

- 127.0.0.1
- localhost
- computer name

But why am I not able to connect using the SQL Server name (the default one : MSSQLServer) ?

Comment: Just use your PCNAME.

Comment: yep but I should be able to connect using the sql server name.

Comment: **No**, you are **NOT** able to connect using `MSSQLSERVER` because by definition, the **default instance** has no instance name. Only if you install a non-default instance, **then** you **must** use the instance name to connect to it.